# Word for a person who is "in charge"?

Tags: single-word-requests

When you contact organization units like a department, an agency, etc., there is usually a main person whom you should contact. He/she is also the main responsible person for critical problems. Should we call him/her *person in charge*? Is there a simple word for that?

And, is following right?

> - Who is the person in charge of this department?
> - To contact the person in charge of that department, dial 234 567.
> - Do you know that department's person in charge?

P.S. The problem behind: It's used in a data table, a column "PersonInCharge" seems too complicated, though. And, the *manager* or the *supervisor* may be someone else, so I'm not likely to use them as well.

Comment: In my department it's "Mike".

Comment: The first two usages are right, but not "Do you know that department's person in charge?".

Comment: In the 80's it was "Charles".

Comment: Everyone knows it's Tony Danza

Comment: [HMFIC](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hmfic) would fit nicely at the head of a column.

Comment: As for your database question:  I would have no problem with naming a column *PersonInCharge*.

Comment: Like a boss ...

Comment: Voting to close. No single English word could possibly fit all real-world contexts, and OP only wants a database field name anyway. As @John Y says, just call the column *PersonInCharge*, and let's move on.

Comment: **The word could be Foreman**

Comment: P.I.C. , c/o , or *lead*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the context of a department or realm of work, I would use *manager*, as in:

> Is the manager of this department in today?

In the context of an individual I would probably use *supervisor*, although manager would work as well:

> May I speak with your supervisor please?

If you are talking about a specific task rather than a department, you might use the phrase *in charge* like this:

> Who is in charge of restocking the snack cupboard?

Lastly the verb *head up* can also be useful in contexts of projects or teams:

> Who is heading up the backup team?
>   Who is heading up the security audit?

Comment: In any given organisation it might cause serious ructions if a potentially 'demarcatory' word like *manager* ended up being applied to people who just happened to be in charge of some insignificant subdivision for which that term wasn't normally used.

Comment: @Fumble: Two of the three examples given were questions and I think it's a fair word to use as part of a question. If it comes out in the answer that there isn't a "manager" per-se but there is something else, then so be it and you'll learn what word they do use on the spot.

Comment: Well I voted to close anyway, so you can see where I'm coming from. My point was simply that if a bog-standard report were to be produced from OP's database, using fieldnames as column headings, someone might well be miffed *whatever* 'job-title' sort of word was used.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd tell them to go get a life and stop being so delicate. Time should not be invested in hypothetically appeasing these people.

Answer (score 8):

In earlier times you would use the word **Manager**

> Can I speak to the manager?

Nowadays with so many titles and since you do not know the specific one that applies in that area (eg: Administrator, Supervisor, Boss etc) , it is getting popular to use "***person in charge***" as in the examples you have used.

Comment: *Manager* is still viable, and I would say preferred.

Answer (score 8):

I can think of two simple words: *head* and *leader*.

Examples:

> - Who is the head [of the department] here?
> - Do you know the department's leader?

Answer (score 3):

I would use superior.

> Can I speak to your superior?

It can work for anyone who is above someone else, even if it's not a managerial position.

Answer (score 2):

The details of your question convey that you are looking for something specific, since you did not approve of manager or supervisor.

You said:

> > "person whom you should contact...."
> >
> > "also the main responsible person for critical problems...."

This means that you are not talking about the person in authority, you are talking about a [Contact] or [EmergencyContact]

Answer (score 1):

The main person you should contact is possibly just the contact, or could be the liaison. Could also just be the boss.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to a Francophone country and ask for the *chef* or a Spanish-speaking country and ask for *el jefe*, the *chief* of the business or restaurant will respond (one would hope without a cleaver).

When I lived in French-speaking West Africa, I would address any *gendarme* as *chef*. He would usually crack a smile, as I had also planted the notion that I was not a tourist. It took a year of speaking French before I realized that the *chef* in a restaurant was the *chief* of the restaurant, and that *chief* had a broad applicability.

As I was building a house, I would visit every day during construction. The phrase that I learned to request the foreman was *el jefe*. Here is the same word in Spanish.

If you asked for the *chief* you would probably get the right person, although in the English-speaking world this might sound out-of-place. If you asked for the *chef*, you would probably get the right person in a restaurant, but a puzzled look if the hearer were not a fan of *Hell's Kitchen*.

Comment: In English - in England at least - asking for "The boss" will usually get you what you need in the above situations.  Whilst it's not necessarily the actual title of whoever you want, it colloquially describes them.  I don't know, though, how well it translates to international Englishes - I'd guess it would work in America at least.

Answer (score 1):

Your question contains a good answer, in my view.  "Responsible" fits the bill perfectly.

So

> Who is responsible for this department?
>
> Who is responsible for bug reports?
>
> Who is responsible for fixing burst pipes?

"Responsible" doesn't necessarily imply "in charge" or "superior", even though it will often be the same thing.

I think your column name could just be "Responsible", or "ResponsibleUser" or whatever fits your naming structure.

Comment: This sounds like Spanish or French: el responsable, le responsable. It doesn't work so well in English for a PIC.

Comment: @Lambie It's for use in a database column name, though, rather than prose. I agree that "the responsible" is not good English.

Answer (score 0):

Team Leader is another term that I hear used more often. You could always plump for good ol' "gaffer" if it comes down to it.

Answer (score 0):

**Manager** is perfectly suitable as someone who is responsible for running the shots. **Line manager** can be used to denote the next hierarchical step.

The issue you are encountering is that different organisations like to use different words, in some fields other words are more standard. It does not detract from the fact that a supervisor is indeed a manager. The word just focuses on a different aspect of the individual's responsibility.

If you want my advice, call it whatever you call it within your organisation. This is just a database field name, no one has to see it apart from the developers, heck, you could build in aliases with multiple names if you want people to run direct queries against it.

Answer (score 0):

I like the word **Commander**. It's just so epic.