# What is a noun for "one who is responsible"?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

The word "responsible" works as an adjective only. What is a *noun* for a person who bears some responsibility (i.e. is accountable for something)?

Note: Originally my question was longer, but the added context seemed to mislead people into providing the wrong answers. I have edited the question and removed the superfluous information.

Comment: A job title cannot be *an adjective*. It is not a title. All people are responsible for something big or small.

Comment: Probably depends on what the responsibilities are.  "Technical lead" is a typical term for the chief technologist in charge of some particular aspect of work.

Comment: @Dan Nestor Please provide more context. What does this person actually do? Scope of responsibilities? Do you have a link?

Comment: I assume the [Little Green Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_green_men) did their research before settling on *Take me to your **leader***.

Comment: @A.P. This is a person responsible for technical aspects in some way. I know this is very generic, but I'm looking for a word that wouldn't change the meaning by being more specific than that.

Comment: `Technical Lead` perhaps?

Comment: @DanNestor And what's the industry or business domain? In tech/IT this could be CTO, assuming you mean the chief technical person.

Comment: @A.P. The industry should be irrelevant, and the job title should apply also to somebody who is not the chief person.

Comment: What's wrong with the classic 'responsible party'?  Do you specifically require a single word?

Comment: Related: [Word for a person who is “in charge”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/32364/53711)

Comment: Just came across a job advert looking for a "Global responsible", by a German-speaking company though. See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/353819/can-responsible-be-used-as-a-noun

Answer (score 4):

I would just say "responsible person." Where I work, we assign tasks to the appropriate person for each item in any of our action lists. That person becomes the "responsible person."

Answer (score 2):

Well sometimes I used *Person in Charge* (PIC) in some of my school events, I think it's even suited in the workplace.

Edit:

[The Person-in-Charge (PIC)](http://www.foodsafe.ae/pic/)

> In any food establishment will often be the
>   person who has the overall responsibility for running that Location
>   during the entire time of operation. If there are multiple shifts, the
>   PIC will be responsible for the proper functioning of the food
>   establishment’s operation during the work shift.
>
> The PIC can be the
>   owner of the business or a designated person, such as a shift leader,
>   chef, kitchen manager or similar individual who is always present in
>   the work site and has direct authority, control or supervision over
>   employees who engage in the storage, preparation, display or service
>   of foods.   The PIC is accountable to their employer and the
>   government for making sure that they and the employees on their shift
>   are following established policies and procedures for food safety. - Foodsafe.ae

Comment: Welcome to ELU bryan, the phrase you mentioned seems to be related to the question. In order to qualify your answer, can you add some factual information from another source, other than yourself, that might help others to learn more about the term you've mentioned in future answers. In this case, I have found some information from another source, and added it to your answer, but please do likewise for other answers you post.

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about **assignee**?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with **Technical Operations Manager**.

> *Technical Operations Manager: Job Description, Education, and Salary*

[**technicaloperations.com**](http://www.operationsmanager.com/what-is-operations-management/technical-technology-manager/)

Answer (score 0):

If "xxx manager" don't fit, you may say **man of responsibility**.

This expression means that such man assumes(ed) his responsibilities, rather than he is(was) given responsabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I think in life there are a lot of things you can be resposible for.
I was working some years as a crewleader, where were coming up a lot of different situations to manage. Here in Germany, a lot of companies envolved in risky business or production, such as transport, events, chemicals, electricity, or healthcare are under obligation to employ a "safety officer" or a "safety adviser". As a Crewleader, I always had to communicate with our technical project-leader or the managers. In "Project-Process-Managment" you learn that there a special contracts, wich include special fees for as example, an "ultimate responsibilty" including penalty-payments in the case the project will not achieve its goal. Based on that, and in accordance with a business examination there are the following designations: Head or Head-Office, Manager, Member of the panel, Officer, Leader, Supervisor, or the Captain of a ship. Not to forget, Council.

Answer (score 0):

Many Europeans will turn the adjective or verb to a noun  such a 'approval will be sought from the responsible'.  This is incorrect and should be'approval will be sought from the responsible person'.

Comment: Please add a source for your claim. One might say "the **one** responsible", in which case it is perfectly fine. The use as you say may be a mistranslation (on their part), for example the German ['Verantwortliche'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verantwortliche) is a noun meaning *the one responsible*. They may have mistakenly translated to English without adding *the one*. The same reasoning holds for the French ['le responsable'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/responsable#Noun)

Answer (score -1):

How about a *technical supervisor?*

Comment: Please explain why this is a good choice. One way to do this is to cite a dictionary entry.

Answer (score -1):

How about **Technical Manager**?  Or **Technical Administrator**?

Comment: Please explain why this is a good choice. One way to do this is to cite a dictionary entry.

Answer (score -2):

I think the word "**Catalyst**" could be the one that you need.

Find the examples [Catalyst](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-catalysts.html)

Comment: Might "overseer" do in this case?  It is native-English equivalent of the Latin-based "supervisor"--and of the Greek-based "episcopus" (from which our "bishop" is derived).