# Word for "the one who is responsible"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word meaning, "the one who is responsible." Perhaps "responsiblant" as in, "She is the initial responsiblant of this task."

Comment: Your example is ambiguous. Do you mean she is responsible for performing the task (assignee) or she is responsible for seeing that it is done (assigner) ?

Comment: In addition to the other comments, *responsible* can also mean *the person to blame* (e.g. *culprit*) or *the person in charge*. What meaning of the word are you using? Your question doesn't distinguish between the two. (Or between assignee and assigner.)

Comment: Old joke: Elderly important looking man walks into an office c. 1920, and asks "Who is responsible here?" Office boy: "If you mean the one wot always gets the blame, that's me".

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/353819/177853

Answer (score 1):

As this is quite ambiguous, as Colm has said, I'm taking it that you mean 'the one who has committed the act'.  The closest word I can get here is '*perpetrator*', though it obviously won't fit all contexts.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/perpetrator

Answer (score 1):

Not to riff too much on *perpetrator* (+1), but the similiar -ors like *originator* or *progenitor* or *creator* or *owner* are perhaps equally apt.  There's not enough context in the question at this time to really choose the best.

Answer (score 0):

In life critical industries (health, transportation & fire safety) through European England there are two synonymous terms with slight variations in use.

**A competent person** see http://www.hse.gov.uk/involvement/competentperson.htm

whose role is usually filled by a

[CRE - Contractors **Responsible Engineer**](https://www.railwaypeople.com/Rail-Jobs/Search/cre/ENGLAND?search_term=cre&TownOrCity=ENGLAND&search_location=ENGLAND&MatchType=exact&GeoPlaceId=10022&SearchDistance=100&DistanceMultiplier=0.62137) or

(Contract) **Responsible Person** (RP) see http://pharmaexpertsltd.com/responsible-person-rp/